# R cannot assign row names to the matrix output of get()

Tags: r, matrix

I am looking to assign row names to a matrix using R's rownames() function. I have a string that contains the name of my matrix, a list of row names I want to assign, and get the value of matrix name via the get() function.

Calling rownames() on just the output of the get() function throws an error, but if I assign the output of get() to a variable THEN use rownames() it works.

```r
mat = "matrix1"  # the name of my matrix variable, as a string
components = c("1", "2", "3")  # my row names

temp = get(mat)  # temp now holds the value of matrix1

# This fails
> rownames(get(mat)) = components
Error in rownames(get(mat)) = components : 
  could not find function "get<-"

# But this works
> rownames(temp) = components
>
```

I understand that this is an easy workaround, simply assigning the get() output to a variable, I am just new to R and am very interested as to why my nested function calls don't work.

I would expect R to simply output a matrix with my new row names to the terminal and then terminate.

Comment: If you are new to R, you should avoid the use of `get()`. That level of indirection makes everything harder to work with in R. Typically we prefer named lists which using strings to point to objects. It makes everything much easier to work with. But `get()` returns the value that a given variable name points to. It does not allow you to modify that variable value which is what happens when you assign to rownames.

Comment: Names lists look like exactly what I was going for. I needed something more-or-less equivalent to a python dictionary where I was able to keep a the value along with a key for reference later. Thank you for the advice!